# How to resolve ASP.NET DataContext connection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have the following error with my ASP.NET web site. I have just moved it to another PC. Got IIS running, SQL Server Express & changed the Data Source machine name to the new machine name. However on any page with DB access, I get the error shown in the screenshot:
[image: Server error in Application]

innovations-news.aspx creates a new DataContext thus:

```
dataContext = new DataContext(Config.ConnectionString);
```

My Config class returns the connection string based on current IP. For example:

```
return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Development"].ConnectionString;
```

Which is in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Development" connectionString="Data Source=WORK51C0\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Jri;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The following is from LinqToSql1.designer.cs

```
public DataContext() : 
            base(global::Jri.Data.Properties.Settings.Default.JriConnectionString1, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

Any advice on how best to debug this? Or perhaps even you know whats wrong?!

Thanks,

Comment: Is WORK51C0 the name of the new workstation ? Does it have SQL Express, with that instance name, and does it have integrated security switched on ? Can you connect with Sql Server Management Studio ?

Comment: is `connection` or `mappingSource` null?

Comment: Does your Jri.Data.DataContact derive from Linq.DataContext?  We could use a bit more information...

Comment: OK well Im on Windows 7 Home edition and I just found out it does not support Windows Authentication. What can I do instead?

Comment: Just updated with DataContext functions from LinqToSql1.designer.cs

Comment: So the answer has been 2 fold: finding out that my Config class was indeed returning NULL to the DataContext for the ConnectionString, but then also I had to switch my ConnectionString to SQL Server authentication as on Windows 7 Home there is no Windows Authentication!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well this was an access problem that My Config class with ConfigurationManager. So my temporary solution has been to have the connection string directly outputted by this class rather than try to get it from web.config.

Answer (score 0):

That is an ArgumentNullException.  You are somehow passing null to the constructor or DataContext.

Attach a debugger and see why Config.ConnectionString or mappingSource is returning null.