# Entity Framework 6, Command Interception & Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I was asked to develop auditing for a system at my work. The system has already been completed. 
I think EF 6's Command Interception should work well for my purposes.

However, there are situations like this where we would want to know who sent a request for leave, and we would like to be able to intercept this Insert query.

```
using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
    {
      var result = context.CreateLeavePrerequest(
        leaveRequest.LeaveType,
        leaveRequest.StartDate,
        leaveRequest.EndDate,
        leaveRequest.NumberOfDays,
        leaveRequest.EmployeeComment,
        leaveRequest.HasSupportingDocumentation,
        leaveRequest.ResourceTag,
        leaveRequest.RemainingBalance,
        leaveRequest.ApproverResourceTag,
        leaveRequest.CapturerResourceTag,
        leaveRequest.SupportingDocumentID,
        ref id
        );
```

then the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateLeavePrerequest]
(
  @LeaveType VARCHAR(50) ,
  @StartDate DATETIME ,
  @EndDate DATETIME ,
  @NumberOfDays DECIMAL(18, 5) ,
  @EmployeeComment VARCHAR(512) ,
  @SickNoteIndicator BIT ,
  @ResourceTag INT,
  @RemainingBalance DECIMAL,
  @ApproverResourceTag INT,
  @CapturerResourceTag INT,
  @SupportingDocumentID INT,
  @id INT = 0 OUT
)  
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO [ESS PER LVE PreRequest]
            ( [Resource Tag] ,
              [Leave Type] ,
              [Start Date] ,
              [End Date] ,
              [No Of Days] ,
              [Employee Comments] ,
              [Sick Note Indicator],
              [Status],
              [Remaining Balance],
              [Approver Resource Tag],
              [Capturer Resource Tag],
              [SupportingDocumentID]
            )
            SELECT  @ResourceTag ,
                    @LeaveType ,
                    @StartDate ,
                    @EndDate ,
                    @NumberOfDays ,
                    @EmployeeComment ,
                    @SickNoteIndicator,
                    'Captured',
                    @RemainingBalance,
                    @ApproverResourceTag,
                    @CapturerResourceTag,
                    @SupportingDocumentID;
SELECT @id
END
```

**UPDATE:**

CreateLeavePrerequest is implemented as follows:

```
public ISingleResult<CreateLeavePrerequestResult> CreateLeavePrerequest([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="LeaveType", DbType="VarChar(50)")] string leaveType, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="StartDate", DbType="DateTime")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> startDate, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="EndDate", DbType="DateTime")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> endDate, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="NumberOfDays", DbType="Decimal(18,5)")] System.Nullable<decimal> numberOfDays, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="EmployeeComment", DbType="VarChar(512)")] string employeeComment, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="SickNoteIndicator", DbType="Bit")] System.Nullable<bool> sickNoteIndicator, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ResourceTag", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> resourceTag, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="RemainingBalance", DbType="Decimal(18,0)")] System.Nullable<decimal> remainingBalance, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ApproverResourceTag", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> approverResourceTag, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="CapturerResourceTag", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> capturerResourceTag, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="SupportingDocumentID", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> supportingDocumentID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] ref System.Nullable<int> id)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), leaveType, startDate, endDate, numberOfDays, employeeComment, sickNoteIndicator, resourceTag, remainingBalance, approverResourceTag, capturerResourceTag, supportingDocumentID, id);
        id = ((System.Nullable<int>)(result.GetParameterValue(11)));
        return ((ISingleResult<CreateLeavePrerequestResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

DBCommandInterceptor registration in Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     DbInterception.Add(new Auditor());
 }
```

DBCommandInterceptor implementation:

I implemented this quickly so that I could just see whether I could intercept anything, so it just writes to the Debug window. I have been able to intercept some `Select` queries, but that's not what we want to audit.

```
 public class Auditor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        CreateAuditMessage(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        CreateAuditMessage(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        CreateAuditMessage(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        CreateAuditMessage(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        CreateAuditMessage(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        CreateAuditMessage(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public static void CreateAuditMessage<T>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<T> interceptionContext)
    {
        string message;

        var parameters = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DbParameter param in command.Parameters)
        {
            parameters.AppendLine(param.ParameterName + " " + param.DbType + " = " + param.Value);
        }

        if (interceptionContext.Exception == null)
        {
            message = (parameters.ToString() + "  " + command.CommandText);
        }
        else
        {
            message =  (parameters.ToString() + command.CommandText + "  " + interceptionContext.Exception);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Recently, I've been reading a lot about Entity Framework, but I am not very knowledgeable. 
I have implemented the IDbCommandInterface and registered it etc. I am able to see some other queries being intercepted, but since the above situation is such that the stored procedure is being called "outside" I can't get hold of the parameters.

This is a simple example. Not all the stored procedures that are called in a similar way in the system are so simple.

What would be the best way to change the above situation so that we can apply the interception and thus the auditing?

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555541/how-to-resolve-asp-net-datacontext-connection-error for more insight.

Comment: @jarlh, Sql Server.

Comment: @BijayKoirala, can you please explain to me how the link that you provided is relevant to my question?

Comment: Please show how `context.CreateLeavePrerequest()` is implemented, and was its code generated (if so, using what tool) or was it programmed manually?

Comment: @PeterB, I have updated the original post to show how `context.CreateLeavePrerequest()` is implemented. I assume it was autogenerated by dragging and dropping it into the dbml file. Do you need more detail? I didn't work on this system myself, I've only been pulled in to help with the auditing, but I could ask a colleague.

Comment: Can you show us how your IDbCommandInterceptor implementation and registry??

Comment: The update makes the question even more confusing. The code doesn't seem to be EF6 at all (probably LinqToSql or something). Are you asking to intercept external non EF6 database calls? If yes, this has nothing to do with EF6 command interception, which by definition can intercept only commands executed using EF6 infrastructure.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah... you're right. This isn't EF6 code. I've looked in the solution and there are bits and pieces that look like they've used EF6, but the majority seems to be LINQ-to-SQL. That's one of the reasons I asked this question because even with my scanty knowledge of EF I couldn't see how in the world I could intercept that call to the DB. Part of my confusion was that my manager said that they were using EF6 but I think my manager should also take a better look at the code. ;-)

Comment: @DanielBrughera, see Update 2.

Comment: Given that you've got a mix of tech wrt data access, you might consider implementing an action filter in the methods that call your auditable stuff. Don't know where you are in your overall framework...but inferring from `Global.asax' that you're somewhere around asp.net mvc 4/5. If so, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use **Context Log property** for intercepting any of the DB queries fires using `DataContext`

You can define a constructor on your `DataContext` class like following.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{

    public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
          Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
          //NOTE: Instead of Debug.WriteLine, you can stroe it in DB.

    }
.....
.....
.....
}
```

**What gets logged by Context Log Property?**

- SQL for all different kinds of commands. For example:

  1- Queries, LINQ queries, eSQL queries, and raw queries.

  2- Inserts, updates, and deletes generated as
  part of SaveChanges

  3- Relationship loading queries such as those
  generated by lazy loading
- Parameters
- Whether or not the command is being executed asynchronously
- A timestamp indicating when the command started executing
- Whether or not the command completed successfully, failed by throwing
  an exception, or, for async, was canceled
- Some indication of the result value
- The approximate amount of time it took to execute the command. Note
  that this is the time from sending the command to getting the result
  object back. It does not include time to read the results.

To read more about. Logging to different places, Result Logging, Formatting etc, you can check [**Logging and intercepting database operations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer below approach to execute SQL Stored Procedures from my Application, as I have used this to execute stored procedures from remote servers as well. The only thing you need to take care is to pass correct formatted parameters to respective Parameter type.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateLeavePrerequest", con)) {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       cmd.Parameters.Add("@LeaveType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = leaveType;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = startDate;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = endDate;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumberOfDays", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = numberOfDays;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeComment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeComment;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@SickNoteIndicator", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sickNoteIndicator;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResourceTag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = resourceTag;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@RemainingBalance", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = remainingBalance;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproverResourceTag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = approverResourceTag;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@CapturerResourceTag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = capturerResourceTag;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupportingDocumentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = supportingDocumentID;
       cmd.Parameters["@id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

For any NULL values Check for

```
DBNull.Value
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks!